# Python: function that gets n-th element of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of strings like

```
['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ']
```

and I want a list of strings containing the first letter of each string, i.e.

```
['A', 'D', 'G'].
```

I thought about doing that using map and the function that returns the first element of a list: `my_list[0]`. But how can I pass this to `map`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* use a list comprehension, like [@avasal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15741308/1219006) since it's more pythonic, but here's how to do it with `map`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter   
>>> L = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ'] 
>>> map(itemgetter(0), L)
['A', 'D', 'G']
```

Comment: @Elrond1337 No problem, this method would be faster but it would only be premature optimization and would go unnoticeable in almost every situation. Definitely go with the better looking list comp

Answer (score 5):

you can try

```
In [14]: l = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ']

In [15]: [x[0] for x in l]
Out[15]: ['A', 'D', 'G']
```

Comment: note: lowercase `l` can be confused with the number `1`. You should change your list name.

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension like so:

```
results = [i[0] for i in mySrcList]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
l1=['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ']
l1=map(lambda x:x[0], l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['ABC','DEF','GHI']
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(i[0])
```

`b` is the array you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
>>> myArray=['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHIJ']
>>> newArray=[]
>>> for i in map(lambda x:x[0],myArray):
...     newArray.append(i)
...
>>> print(newArray)
['A', 'D', 'G']
```